# How to create java multi dimensional array java for xml

Tags: java, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

I am using java client to call the webservice .

There is one field :e.g. items  ,which requires multi dimensional array.

In sample xml it is as follows :

```
<ns:DataItem>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
   <arr:ArrayOfstring>
       <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
       <arr:string>1</arr:string>
       <arr:string>Item</arr:string>
       <arr:string>Company</arr:string>
       <arr:string>None</arr:string>
       <arr:string>10000</arr:string>
       </arr:ArrayOfstring>
 </ns:DataItem>
```

In java webservice client: It is declared as: `java.lang.String[][] items`

Please help me in this. How do I initialize java array i.e. items as per the xml sample.
What I have tried so far is as follows:

```
   String[][] items= new String [][] {{ "1", "Item","company","None","200000"}  };
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Your initialization looks just fine to me.

Comment: looks fine. Do you have errors you could share?

Comment: @RogerGustavsson ,Yes I just found out. it is working and perfect. It is the  webservice that is throwing some error. Thanks . It is resolved.